Trying to fetch values from a specific column in Monday.com using GraphQL
I have a column name "XYZ" for which I need to fetch the values/data from all the groups on the board
query {
  boards (ids: 12345) {
    items  {
      id
      name
      column_values {
         id: XYZ,
         title: Name XYZ
      }
    }
  }
}

Above is the GraphQl query that Im trying to use, But It results in an error
errors": [
{
"message": "Field 'items' doesn't exist on type 'Board'",

You need to try something like below,
query {
  boards (ids: 12345) {
     id
      name
      columns{
        id
        description
      }
     
  }
}

You can try this on the API Playground
